# How do plastic containers and other thrash end up in the ocean

Tags: ecology, marine-biology, environment

There are many photos of the ocean, which in some parts is littered with all sorts of waste, often plastic bags, containers etc. But I just wonder - how do such large amounts land in the ocean/sea? Isn't waste disposed at secure sites - so such a bug would either be recycled or in the worst case end up on some landfill? Of course rogue companies or entities could occasionally dump some thrash into the ocean, but the massive amounts of it seem surprising to me. 
Beside, often the argument is to not use plastic bags, containers etc. but simply USING them doesn't put them in the sea. So what does, and can it be stopped?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has little to do with biology! [SustainableLiving.SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/) might accept this kind of question.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to another Stack Exchange, I was looking for one but this one seemed most fitting. Certainly I don't intend to spam, so if there is one more suitable I am more than happy to move the question here.

Comment: I am sure you did not mean to spam. As your post has been now posted on sustainableLiving.SE (and has a good reception), you might want to delete your post here on Biology.SE.